# Is there a way after reading lines from text file set the result as variable which can be then used in js script

Tags: bash

I am at a wall, I have a bash script which performs a command that afterwards save the output in a text file named 'test-example1.txt' in this case. Afterwards I have used the code below to display/read the output from that text file which will be 1 line with an exact value.

The question is now since I am not sure, how to set that specific value as a variable and afterwards call a javascript which will perform X function using that variable.

Thank you all for taking time reading and suggesting solutions.

```
filename=test-example1.txt
IFS=$'\n'
for next in `cat $filename`; do
   eval echo "$next getting variable from $filename" 
done
echo 'That is the Variable-Id'
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the `next` result as a variable using eval:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for next in `cat $filename`; do
   eval "$next=next"
done
```

You mention call a ***javascript*** function with a bash variable. Well you could use the variable with node.js:

**my-node.js** example:

```
console.log(process.argv[2]);
```

And call your my-node.js script from bash like this:

```
node my-node.js "$next"
```

Comment: In this case I am using a normal javascript which will afterwards use the value from the '$next' as a variable to perform an invalidation. In this case could you assist and give an example after the 'done' how to call the javascript (not node, but normal) which is using aws-sdk > https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/master/dist/aws-sdk.js .

Also here is the result after the change:
`
example-run.sh: line 19: [=next: command not found
example-run.sh: line 19: CORRECTVARIABLEFROMTEXTFILE=next: command not found
example-run.sh: line 19: ]=next: command not found
` @suspectus

Comment: Edited the code and it looks now like this >> filename=test-example1.txt
IFS=$'\n'
for next in `cat $filename`; do
#echo " ${yellow} $next ${reset} getting variable from $filename" 
#eval -e "$next=next"
echo "${yellow} $next ${reset}"
done
echo -e "${red}The Distribution-Id is the CAPSLOCK output in Yellow! ${reset}"
echo "$next"
exit 0

The output that now I receive is >> Give the script few moments to run...
 [ 
     "DISTRIBUTION-ID-Value-FromFile" 
 ] 
The Distribution-Id is the CAPSLOCK output in Yellow! 
]

Comment: hello Vasil - you should update your post with your edits. They don't read well as comments. Do you still have a question? Did you find my answer useful?

Comment: BTW this is from AWS docs `Whether and how you install the AWS SDK for JavaScript depends whether the code executes in Node.js modules or browser scripts.` I don't see how you can run "normal" js from the command line.

Comment: In this case I simply need to run the bash script to get the 'DistributionId' and afterwards set it as a variable. Once it is set as variable as in this case '$next' how to call a ready to use invalidation javascript, but the thing that comes to my mind is that even if in the javascript it is set to use variable '$next' since it is printed in the bash will the script be able to get that value or it would be better to simply run the bash-script which afterwards save the Distribution-Id that is saved as variable="$next"  in the javascript and then execute the javascript?

Comment: yes, it will be better. javascript is an interpreted scripting language and there is no binding that I know of to connect bash to javascript, other than the way of the example in my answer. If you have my answer useful, would you consider upvoting it? thanks!

Comment: Hmm so the only way is to export the variable '$next' in the javascript which he can afterwards use, any idea how can that be performed with the current code. As for up-voting unfortunately I don't have high enough reputation otherwise I would do that in an instant :)

Comment: Thanks! Yes as far as I know.  Why not use my suggestion ? e.g. `node my-node.js "$next"`  ? If you want to validate the value - why not do that in bash??